# Writing an OS X kernel extension to implement Linux's SO_BINDTODEVICE socket option

Tags: c, macos, networking, driver, kernel-extension

I want to be able to force a socket through a specific network interface. In Linux the kernel allows a programmer to achieve this by setting said socket option - but in OS X I'm in the dark.

And hence my title question - is it possible? Has it been done? I'm not looking into re-implementing the IP stack, just enabling the usage of the bind-to-interface option.

Comment: And standard `bind(2)` with particular interface addres does not work for you?

Comment: @NikolaiNFetissov: Can you elaborate on bind(2). Is this API, command line utility or something else?

Comment: @Dor: Was you able to figure it out?

Comment: Read the manual - `man 2 bind`. It's one of the fundamental network-related system calls.

Comment: bind() won't do me any good, as the system doesn't guarantee the call will bind the socket to a specific interface - but only to a specific address.

Comment: And for raw sockets with IP_HDRINCL, the address you specified in bind or sendto is completely ignored.

Answer (score -1):

Use the RFC 3542 interface for selecting outgoing interfaces (IPV6_PKTINFO). https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3542#section-6